# Last statement of While Loop "[string: command not found"

Tags: bash

I have a while loop to determine if user entered a new line and will exit once the user enters anything but a new line with the following snippet:

```
...
while [$abc -e ""]
do
read -p " enter something besides new line " abc
done
...
```

Say the user presses 'Enter' 4 times followed by 'someNonNewLineString' the output will be

```
enter something besides new line

enter something besides new line 

enter something besides new line 

enter something besides new line 

line 1 [someNonNewLineString: command not found
```

from a control perspective, it works the way as expected as this loop is exited once the user enters anything besides 'Enter' but why is that last statement returned saying command not found?

also, is this the right way of approaching this (detect if user entered new line, if yes, re prompt for something else)?

Comment: Why are you using `-e` ? That checks if a file exists, use `=` to compare strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spaces around `[` and `]`, compare using `=`.

```
while [ "$abc" = "" ]
```

Comment: changing it to while [ "$abc" -e "" ] gives me:

[: -e: binary operator expected

when I enter 'enter'

Comment: This worked! thanks. guess i got -e , -eq , =, == all mixed up.

Comment: @Boboyum if I were you I'd forget about `==` as it doesn't do anything different to `=` and is non-standard, so only works in some shells like bash.